# Replacing alternate spaces with newline?

Tags: unix, replace

I am trying to replace the alternate spaces with newlines using UNIX.
I tried using tr command in UNIX but was unable modify it to replace alternate spaces.

Sample input:
0 1 2 3 4 5
Sample output:
0 1
2 3
4 5

How do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` might help in this case:

```
echo "0 1 2 3 4 5" | awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    {
        if ((i-1)%2 == 0)
        {
            printf "%d ",$i;
        }
        else
        {
            print $i
        }
    }
}
'
```

We split by space and have 6 items. We, then, are looping through all fields and outputting each field. Every other field is output in a new line with `print $i`; otherwise we print using `printf "%d ",$i;` and not create a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "0 1 2 3 4 5" | sed 's/\([^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]*\) */\1\n/g'
```

This can be made shorter with GNU sed which has the `'+'` notation.